# Joomla Sendmail() causes 504 Gateway Time-out in siteground

Tags: joomla

I am using `JEvent` to create the event.

In the Event detail page, I am sending the email invitation to the 200 user.
When send 200 email using joomla `sendMail()`

```
($this->sendMail($user->email, $user->name, $iuser->email, 
                  $subject, $message, 1, null, $bcc);)
```

I am getting Gateway Time-out error.

The Error message as follow:

> Gateway Time-out "The Gateway did not receive a timely response from
>   the upstream server or application."

Comment: A gateway timeout means the gateway server could not comunicate in due time with the server running your application. Does the problem persist if you reduce the amount of sent emails? What exactly is your question?

Comment: Sending bulk emails is a complex process with many legal issues involved, not to mention that either your domain or the host could be marked as a spammer by the companies that do that and then no mail will go through. Therefore you need to throttle your emails to a smaller number per hour or bundle or both. Use a well established extension to manage this.